# Problem involving 'alphabetization' of sets of row elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a variable **setSize** (it can take value 2 or 3), and a numpy array **v**.
The number of columns in **v** is divisible by **setSize**.  Here's a small sample:

```
import numpy as np

setSize = 2

# the array spaces are shown to emphasize that the rows 
# are made up of sets having, in this case, 2 elements each. 

v = np.array([[2,5,  3,5,  1,8],
              [4,6,  2,7,  5,9],
              [1,8,  2,3,  1,4],
              [2,8,  1,4,  3,5],
              [5,7,  2,3,  7,8],
              [1,2,  4,6,  3,5],
              [3,5,  2,8,  1,4]])
```

PROBLEM:  For the rows that have **all elements unique**, I need to **ALPHABETIZE** the sets.
For example: set 1,14  would precede  set 3,5, which would precede set 5,1.
As a final step, I need to eliminate any duplicated rows that may result.

In this example above, the array rows having indices 1,3,5,and 6 have unique elements,
so these rows must be alphabetized.  The other rows are not changed.
Further, the rows `v[3]` and `v[6]`, after alphabetization, are now identical.   One of them may be dropped.

The final output looks like:

```
v =          [[2,5,  3,5,  1,8],
              [2,7,  4,6,  5,9],
              [1,8,  2,3,  1,4],
              [1,4,  2,8,  3,5],
              [5,7,  2,3,  7,8],
              [1,2,  3,5,  4,6]]
```

I can identify the rows having unique elements with code like below, but I stuck with the alphabetization code.

```
s = np.sort(v,axis=1)
v[(s[:,:-1] != s[:,1:]).all(1)]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`lexsort`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have unsuitable rows dropped with:

```
s = np.sort(v, axis=1)
idx = (s[:,:-1] != s[:,1:]).all(1)
w = v[idx]
```

Then you can get orders of each row with `np.lexsort` on a reshaped array:

```
w = w.reshape(-1,3,2)
s = np.lexsort((w[:,:,1], w[:,:,0]))
```

Then you can apply fancy indexing and reshape it back:

```
rows, orders = np.repeat(np.arange(len(s)), 3), s.flatten()
v[idx] = w[rows, orders].reshape((-1,6))
```

If you need to drop duplicated rows, you can do it like so:

```
u, idx = np.unique(v, return_index=True, axis=0)
output = v[np.sort(idx)]
```

Visualization of process:

[image]

Sample run:

```
>>> s
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
>>> rows
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
>>> orders
array([1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
>>> v[idx]
array([[2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 9],
       [1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6],
       [1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5]])
>>> v
array([[2, 5, 3, 5, 1, 8],
       [2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 9],
       [1, 8, 2, 3, 1, 4],
       [1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5],
       [5, 7, 2, 3, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6],
       [1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5]])
>>> output
array([[2, 5, 3, 5, 1, 8],
       [2, 7, 4, 6, 5, 9],
       [1, 8, 2, 3, 1, 4],
       [1, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5],
       [5, 7, 2, 3, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: This is getting very close!  Two points: a) your code correctly 'alphabetizes' the array rows that have all unique values (indices 1,3,5,6), but the problem states "the other rows are not changed".   So we need to keep rows (indices 0,2,4).   b) The X should be a v.  Could you suggest a fix to point a)?

Comment: @user109387 Good catch. So I did these cosmetics, check out.

Comment: I'm new to lexsort, so I appreciate the detailed descriptions.